# Ember.js How to add unrelated content(side bar/footer/modal) and pass id

Tags: ember.js

I am working a fairly simple Emberjs application. However, I am having trouble figuring out one piece.

This is a simple demo app for a client. I am making the different pages and having a modal dialog pop up when the user comes to each page. I am using the fixture adapter and have content for the modals for each page specified as a fixture.

I have my pages that I navigate to and some have an id that I pass in. I have my routes defined for each of these.

Now that I have all of that set up, I would like to add the modals to the page by passing the id in through the url. It doesn't seem like I should have to specify a modal route inside of each resource though.

For example:

This is the code I have to start with:

```
    this.resource('test', {path: '/test'}, function() {
        this.resource('question', { path: '/:test_id'});
    });
    this.resource('home', {path: '/home'});
```

When I want to add the modals it seems like I need to do something like this, but it doesn't seem right that I have to add the modal as a route to every resource I have. Then I would also have an enormous number of templates/controllers etc.

```
    this.resource('test', {path: '/test'}, function() {
        this.resource('question', { path: '/:test_id'}, function() {
            this.route('modal', {path: '/modal/:modal_id'});
        });
    });
    this.resource('home', {path: '/home'}, function() {
        this.route('modal', {path: '/modal/:modal_id'});
    });
```

This may be because I am a rookie with Emberjs, but I haven't seen anything to offer an alternative for unrelated dynamic content on a page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this actions in your application route

```
App.ApplicationRoute = App.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    showModal: function() {
      this.render('modal', {
        outlet: 'modal',
        into: 'application'
      });
    },
    hideModal: function() {
      this.disconnectOutlet({
        outlet: 'modal',
        parentView: 'application'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can use query params in combination with setupController on the other Routes

```
this.resource('test', {path: '/test'}, function() {
    this.resource('question', { path: '/:test_id',queryParams: ['modalId']});
});
```

and question route should be somthing like this

```
App.QuestionRoute = App.Route.extend({
    setupController:function(controller,model,queryParams){
        controller.set('model',model);
        if(queryParams.modalId){
            var modalModel;
            //Set your modal model, here you have access to the store, etc
            this.controllerFor('modal').set('model', modalModel);
            this.send('showModal')
        }
        else{
            this.controllerFor('modal').set('model', null);
            this.send('hideModal');
        }
    }
});
```

Note: queryparams is an optional feature you shoul activate
http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/feature-flags/

You ca use the link-to helper, and transitionTo...

link-to example, for open the modal with an id 1

```
{{#linkTo modelId=1}}modal 1{{/linkTo}}
```

For closing

```
{{#linkTo modelId=false}}Close modal{{/linkTo}}
```

More info on query params https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3182

Comment: I don't like having to add to all of my routes, but this seemed like the most reasonable answer

Comment: You can try to add the setupController hook to the applicationRoute, it depends on how are your modals related to a particular Route, or make a routeModal mixin and add it to your routes definition when neccesary

Answer (score 0):

You could pass content via the URL and use this in your route. In your route, there's a model hook and you should have access to a params object that will contain all of the URLs dynamic segments.

You could make it a nested route as in your example, or you could have it a the same level has the resources. Which means you won't have to repeat it.

Not sure this answers the question. It feels like I might be missing some information.

What are you displaying the modals? I usually display something that is related to the outer resource, so I personally avoid having a global 'modal' route. In that case, I simply render the modal in a different outlet and  have a route/view that encapsulate some of the modal functionality, but I'm not sure if this is the same you would need.